# camunda RestApi CaseDefinition not returning id

Tags: camunda

In camunda, a call to the 
**URL:**`http://localhost:8080/engine-rest/case-definition/key/loanApplication` 
Doesn't return me caseId, which I want to use to start/process the loan application.

 Is there any other workaround to achieve this?

**Output**

```
{
  "id": "loanApplication:7:d75526c5-ccce-11e6-9ca3-3252cbbbb2e3",
  "key": "loanApplication",
  "category": "http://bpmn.io/schema/cmmn",
  "name": null,
  "version": 7,
  "resource": "loancmmndiag.cmmn",
  "deploymentId": "d74966ed-ccce-11e6-9ca3-3252cbbbb2e3",
  "tenantId": null
}
```

Use case is: RestCall to perform a work-flow which has **cmmn** & **Dmn** in it.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong REST API call. Your call is retrieving the latest deployed case-definition with the key 'loadApplication'.
To start a case-definition using the REST API, see [Camunda REST API doc](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.6/reference/rest/case-definition/post-create-case-instance/).